# XML "not well-formed" after Android Studio update

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

After I updated Android Studio to take another shot at an old app it throws me an "Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)". Nevertheless, I cannot find the error and Android Studio does not highlight anything for errors...

The three XML files that throw the same error:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

> ```
> <resources>
>     <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
>     <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
>     <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
> </resources>
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/img_fart_up" />
```

I did not manage to cleanly update: I first patched, but got an error with the SDK package so decided to reinstall. But that did not go well, either, because I forgot to de-install the previous installation and had some issues getting the SDK to work.

Maybe I missed some changes to the use of the xmlns:android - thing in the last months?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see an error but that error means there is a typo or something that shouldn't be there in your xml. Have you checked your other xml files (if you have alternative layouts or landscape/portrait folders)? Edit: Should the xml encoding and version be in your resource file at the top?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect, that I assume to have missed some changes to Android. The header does not seem to be necessary here, it does not throw any error.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild. I can't find an error, unless its one of those files in a different layout folder.

Comment: Sometimes whitespace in the beginning of an xml is the culprit. 
Remove any you find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to "rewrite" the code.
I deleted the header and retyped all line breaks. Seems to have been a formating error, as suggested by Lukos.